# Hibernate bag vs idbag

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have looked at the difference between a bag and idbag and I understand the difference between them but what I am trying to understand is would there be a scenario where things could go wrong if bag is used instead of idbag or vice versa. Can some one explain this with an example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Bag` is an unordered collection, and, unlike `idbag`, it doesn't use an extra column for storing each element index.

There's no such thing as a use case where a `bag` would work and an `idbag` would not. The only difference is their efficiency:

1. [Bags are the most efficient inverse collection](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-collections-mostefficentinverse) but they perform poorly for unidirectional one-to-many associations:

> Bags are the worst case since they permit duplicate element values
>   and, as they have no index column, no primary key can be defined.
>   Hibernate has no way of distinguishing between duplicate rows.
>   Hibernate resolves this problem by completely removing in a single
>   DELETE and recreating the collection whenever it changes. This can be
>   inefficient.

2. `idbag` are a legacy hibernate mapping and they were used to provide a [more efficient unidirectional associations alternative](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html#collections-idbag)

You can define an idbag semantics using the JPA [@OrderColumn](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OrderColumn.html) annotation:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
@OrderColumn(name = "index_id")
private List<Employee> employees;
```

This way you can use both [Lists and Sets](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-favoring-sets-vs-bags/) for ordering collections.

So, try to stick to bidirectional associations as they are the most efficient ones and they mimic the database relations better. If you want a certain element index strategy, use the @OrderColumn association.